# Cordova InAppBrowser in Ripple Emulator - "It is like a browser, only it is all up in your app"

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have built a cordova App using VS2013 and version 3 of the CTP. I've just installed VS 2015 and in doing so had to uninstall the CTP as it is now replaced with a new offering from Microsoft.

I can compile and launch in debug mode which brings up the Ripple emulator. However, when I try to login using social media and OAuth instead of redirecting me to Facebook I get the following message from Ripple:

[image]
This prevents logging in and essentially breaks my application. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I have the same problem.  When I copy the code over to PhoneGap desktop app and connect via my windows phone it works as expected.